How to replace sc16is7xx driver with an older version in the current kernel 5.15.0-1065-raspi
My RPi4 device connects to a dual-UART SC16IS752 via spi. It runs Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS 64-bit with the latest kernel version 5.15.0-1065-raspi.
With older kernel versions (prior to somewhere 5.15.0-1053-raspi), I can get data from both serial ports but now only port 0 with later kernel versions. In dev directory, I have both ports ttySC0 and ttySC1. It seems there have been some changes in the driver in the way how it handles the data.
How do I fix this issue without having to compile the source for every raspi kernel version update since they are released quite often?. Can I simply replace sc16is7xx.ko with the older version?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
